# SQL count(*) with having

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, having

I have this query on oracle.

```
SELECT CBG.refs, CBG.cuo, CBG.date, CBG.nber, CG.date, CBG.conso, 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM MAD.VIN CBV
                    WHERE CBV.CUO = CBG.CUO AND 
                        CBV.NBER = CBG.NBER AND
                        CBV.DATE = CBG.DATE AND
                        CBV.REFS = CBG.REFS 
                        GROUP BY CUO , DATE , NBER , REFS )  AS COUNTS ,
                CBG.CONSO_CONCESS AS CONCESS
                FROM MAD.GEN CBG, MAD.CAR_GEN CG
                WHERE CBG.cuo = CG.cuo AND 
                CBG.CONSO_DATE IS NOT NULL AND
                CBG.date = CG.date AND 
                CBG.nber = CG.nber
                HAVING COUNTS > 0;
```

when i run this sql query it gives me an error that says: invalid identifier counts.

How do we get results only if count is greater than a given parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in MySQL, in Oracle we cannot refer to an alias in the `HAVING` clause (aliases can only be referenced in the `ORDER BY` clause).  One workaround would be to put your current logic into a CTE and then filter it.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT CBG.refs, CBG.cuo, CBG.date AS cbg_date, CBG.nber, CG.date AS cg_date,
            CBG.conso,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM MAD.VIN CBV
             WHERE CBV.CUO = CBG.CUO AND 
                   CBV.NBER = CBG.NBER AND
                   CBV.DATE = CBG.DATE AND
                   CBV.REFS = CBG.REFS 
            GROUP BY CUO, DATE, NBER, REFS) AS COUNTS,
            CBG.CONSO_CONCESS AS CONCESS
    FROM MAD.GEN CBG
    INNER JOIN MAD.CAR_GEN CG
        ON CBG.cuo = CG.cuo AND 
           CBG.date = CG.date AND 
           CBG.nber = CG.nber
    WHERE CBG.CONSO_DATE IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT refs, cuo, cbg_date, nber, cg_date, conso, COUNTS, CONCESS
FROM cte
WHERE COUNTS > 0;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Oracle is not "unlike MySQL" in this respect.  MySQL is different from all other databases in allowing `HAVING` clauses in non-aggregation queries.  Some databases do allow aliases in `HAVING` *in an aggregation query* (which Oracle does not), but that is really the root issue here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff To explain my thinking here for why I used the above language: I saw a non aggregation `HAVING` clause using an alias, and assumed that the OP might have either ported this query from MySQL, or perhaps was coming from a MySQL background.  I'm aware that few other databases share MySQL's quirks (generally a good thing IMHO).